# Android WebView run Javascript in all frames (including iframes)

Tags: javascript, android, iframe

In a Soundcloud iframe within a WebView I want to execute the following js: `(document.getElementsByClassName('mobilePrestitial__link')[0]).click()`

In iOS I achieved this by setting `forMainFrameOnly: false`, however I can't seem to find this setting on Android. What can I do to execute said js on all frames so the click gets through?

This is how I am trying it right now but it doesn't work.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String javascript = "javascript:(document.getElementsByClassName('mobilePrestitial__link')[0]).click()\n" +
                    "setTimeout(function() {\n" +
                    "(document.getElementsByClassName('mobilePrestitial__link')[0]).click()\n" +
                    "}, 5000);";
            view.loadUrl(javascript);
        }
    });
```

Update: if anyone else gets stuck with this with the exact same website, namely Soundcloud: they offer you to have a popup-free frame if you upgrade your channel. Maybe that fits your use case, it was what I eventually went with.